# Unable to display Pl/Sql exception output

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, exception

I am working on a Pl/sql procedure and cannot get the exception error message to display. I am able to display the correct value that does not raise the exception. Code below

```
create or replace procedure proc(p_empNo in costs.empNo%type)
is    
  sumCost number;
  noNumber exception;
  pragma exception_init(noNumber, -20001);
begin

  select sum(cost) into sumCost
    from costs
   where empNo = p_empNo;

  if sumCost <= 0 then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'no matching number');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line(sumCost);
  end if;

  exception when noNum then
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
end proc;
```

Basically I am trying to sum for all the employees with the same number. If there is no matching employee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sum(costs) will return null if your employee doesn't exist, as such it will not get caught in your test of

```
if sumCost <= 0 then
```

Because null is not <=0. null is not a number to satisfy a test like this.

Solution:

```
if NVL(sumCost,0) <= 0 then
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
```

command to show dbms_output results.

In SQLDeveloper you can turn on serveroutout in menu View/DBMS Output, then click on green plus in DBMS output window to create subwindow for connection what you need.

Comment: I already have that set on. I am able to display the results when a correct value is passed through the procedure.